# iOS push notifications doesn't work if "aps" informed in JSON

Tags: ios, json, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If I've my app closed and I send a push notification like this:

```
{
     "alert" : "Hello, world!",
     "sound" : "default"
}
```

My app receives push notification correctly. But if I send this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Hello, world!",
        "sound" : "default"
    }
}
```

My app never show the notification.

If my app is opened I received this last notification correctly in delegate `didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]`

Why iOS 8 is not parsing this last notification and showing it like a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code that actually sends a notification it is not clear totally where is the problem, because if you use some library or wrapper it may add `aps` entry itself. Right now, you should continue sending notifications as in the first example and you will also get them in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]`

Comment: Problem was about third party service. They add "aps:" in JSON push notification. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

**For Objective C.**
Take a look That have you Received The Json Correctly. For First    Option You have used i think code like this

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification {


 }
```

This Will Receive a dictionary That you have.  But Second Option You have    sent an Array whose First index has an Dictionary So Replace    NSDictionary with NSArray Then Receive The array

first index & Retrieve The dictionary   like this

```
 (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSArray *)notification {

......

  }
```

**For Swift** This code has worked For me.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        println("Push Received")
        println(userInfo)
        println(userInfo["aps"])

        var state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState

        if state == UIApplicationState.Active {

            println(userInfo)
            println(userInfo["aps"])

            var alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Push", message: "Received", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in

            }))



        }
```